# HP Designjet 500PS admin password reset

Tags: networking, network-printer, laser-printer

I have a Plotter HP Designjet 500PS. Recently I have changed the admin password but I forgot it. Is there any way to reset it?

Comment: Have you tried googling the problem? The top result for 'HP Designjet 500PS password reset' gave me a link to a forum topic in the HP forums with some advice.

Comment: Yes, I have tried, but I have already found a solution for that if you face the same problem you may just go to the I/O Setup then select Card Setup and then select Advanced to choose Card Reset then press ENTER.

Comment: @kirgiz_jigit You could post that as an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Go to the I/O Setup then select Card Setup and then select Advanced to choose Card Reset then press ENTER.